# Loopback 4 extending REST model-endpoints

Tags: rest, crud, loopback4

I have created all of my REST model-endpoints using the REST CRUD model-endpoint generator. I would like add additional endpoints to the generated controller. Is this possible? I can't find any documentation that tells me how to do this. I suppose that I could manually add another controller, but I would prefer the ability to keep everything grouped in a single place.

Comment: Were you able to find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add controllers via 'lb4 controller' and selecting 'empty controller'. Or you can add additional methods to the existing controllers.

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Controllers.html#writing-controller-methods

Comment: OP was asking for the ability to extend routes generated with `lb4 rest-crud`. So if a model named Teacher exists and lb4 rest-crud generates crud operations for it, there is no way to add any new controller with `lb4 controller` to TeacherController.